# CPP include header file results in thousands of errors

Tags: c++, header

When I include this header File "pathfinding.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <BWAPI.h>
#include "BWAPI/TilePosition.h"
#include <vector>
#include "PathNode.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "ArgosMap.h"
#include "MapField.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "ComparePathNodePointer.h"

using namespace BWAPI;

class Pathfinding {

private:
std::vector<PathNode*> openList;
std::vector<PathNode*> closedList;
std::vector<Position*> buildpath(PathNode* targetNode);


void expandNode(PathNode* currentNode, MapField* targetField);
ArgosMap* argosMap;


public: 
Pathfinding();
~Pathfinding();
std::vector<Position*> getShortestPath(MapField* startField, MapField* targetField);
};
```

In this header File "UnitAgent.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <BWAPI.h>
#include <vector>
#include "ArgosMap.h"
#include "Pathfinding.h"



using namespace BWAPI;

class UnitAgent {

protected:
Unit* unit;
UnitType unitType;
int unitID;
std::vector<Position*> trail;
Position target;

public:
UnitAgent(Unit* unit);
std::vector<Position*> getTrail();
Position getTarget();
Position* getPosition();

int getUnitID();
void setTarget(Position target);
void addPositionToTrail(Position* targetLocation);
void moveTo(TilePosition* targetPosition);

};
```

I get like a million errors mostly error C2143, C2065. But thats not true, the errors do not exist. When I include the header file in another file its all totally fine (except naturally for the stuff that needs the specific header file).

Any Ideas what I should check. Anyone an Idea how i can check my C++ Code, in a way Eclipse checks my java code. I mean why doesnt Visual Studio do that?

Comment: The compiler is always right. You do have those errors, at most you don't realize you do.

Comment: Without putting the text of the error it will be nearly impossible for anyone to help.

Comment: Look at the *first* error that's reported, or the error on the earliest line (sometimes errors can be reported out of order), or the first *syntax* error. Syntax errors in particular can confuse the compiler and lead to a cascade of other errors.

Comment: @H2CO3: Strictly speaking, s/always right/*almost* always right/. But yes, you shouldn't assume a compiler error without very strong evidence. "I know my code is right" is not strong evidence.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, actually. (I see you have the `-pedantic` flag turned on :P ) I've seen nasty compiler errors, but I'd assume OP has run into something rather trivial...

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm not sure I have an option to turn it off. 8-)}

Comment: @KeithThompson That's not a problem :)

Comment: have you tried to add #ifndef _filename_h #define _filename_h ..... #endif statements ? i stumpped few times on similar problems with porting PC C++ <-from/to-> ARM/AVR C++ sometimes multiple #include occurence do weird things (and pragmas are not always the same on different compilers). also there can be missing or overloaded some kind of defined constant/macro for some *.h (its useful to #undef unused macros outside their use)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of directive should not be in a header file

```
using namespace BWAPI;
```

Comment: Agreed, but do you think that's the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, why do you need all this

```
#include <BWAPI.h>
#include "BWAPI/TilePosition.h"
#include <vector>
#include "PathNode.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "ArgosMap.h"
#include "MapField.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "ComparePathNodePointer.h"

using namespace BWAPI;
```

in pathfinding.h? Just forward declaring ArgosMap, MapField, PathNode, and Position like

```
class ArgosMap;
class MapField;
class PathNode;
class Position;
```

is sufficient for pathfinding.h looking at the declaration of Pathfinding class, the stuff above should go to pathfinding.cpp if it is necessary for implementation of Pathfinding methods. The less stuff and dependencies you have in your headers, the easier it will be to debug.

Declarations in pathfinding.h look fine, problem is that some of the methods are not implemented/are not implemented properly. To find out what this methods are, you would need to narrow the scope of the problem - by removing unnecessary dependencies to start with.

Including pathfinding.h in files that do not use it's methods/methods from other headers included would always work fine...

Comment: The strange thing is, it also works in an other file, where i also need pathfinding.h and need the same methods.

Comment: That's another thing that I wanted to mention - class Pathfinding is not used anywhere in the header UnitAgent.h, so problem should be in one of the headers on top of Pathfinding. Refactoring code to include the least possible dependencies in headers would make it a lot easier to read the code and find those types of errors. As someone mentioned in the comment above, without compiler error it is impossible to figure out what exactly is wrong...